# flutter Storage local for web flutter

Tags: flutter

I used storageData for mobile and not problem for me, below code for
mobile : in android is ok

````
```class UserStoredData {
  late DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo; // = DeviceInfoPlugin();

  static const PREFERENCE_NAME = "userPreferences";

  static const REGISTER_STATE = "registerState";

  // static const USER_NAME = "userName";
  static const DEVICE_ID = "deviceId";
  static const UNIQUE_ID = "uniqueId";
  static const USER_TOKEN = "userToken";
  static const USER_PHONE = "userPhone";
  static const USER_LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME = "userLastAttemptTime";
  static const WATCHED_INTRO_HOME = "watchedIntroHome";
  static const WATCHED_INTRO_ORDER = "watchedIntroOrder";
  static const ACTIVE_USER = "activeUser";

  FlutterSecureStorage storage = const FlutterSecureStorage(
      aOptions: AndroidOptions(encryptedSharedPreferences: true),webOptions: WebOptions(),wOptions: WindowsOptions()
      );

  UserStoredData({required this.deviceInfo});

  Future<void> setValue(String name, dynamic value) async {
    await storage.write(key: name, value: value.toString());
  }

  Future<int?> readIntValue<T>(String name) async {
 //   var readData1 = await storage.read(key: name);
    storage.containsKey(key: name);
    var readData = await storage.read(key: name);

    if (readData != null && int.tryParse(readData) != null) {
      return int.parse(readData);
    } else {
      return null; // or provide a default value, depending on your use case
    }
  }

  Future<String?> readStringValue<T>(String name) async {
    var readData = await storage.read(key: name);
    return readData;
  }

  setRegisterState(RegisterState registerState) {
    setValue(REGISTER_STATE, registerState.index);
  }

  Future<RegisterState> getRegisterState() async {
    var state = await readIntValue<int?>(REGISTER_STATE);
    return RegisterState.values[state ?? 0];
  }

  setActiveUser(int userID) {
    setValue(ACTIVE_USER, userID);
  }

  Future<int?> getActiveUser() async {
    return readIntValue<int?>(ACTIVE_USER);
  }

// setUsername(String username) {
//   setValue(USER_NAME, username);
// }
//
// String getUsername() {
//   return readValue<String?>(USER_NAME) ?? "";
// }
//
// setUserPass(String password) {
//   setValue(USER_PASSWORD, password);
// }
//
// String getUserPass() {
//   return readValue<String?>(USER_PASSWORD) ?? "";
// }

  setDeviceID(String deviceID) {
    setValue(DEVICE_ID, deviceID);
  }

  Future<String?> getDeviceID() async {
    return readStringValue<String?>(DEVICE_ID);
  }

  setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
    setValue(USER_PHONE, userPhone);
  }

  Future<String?> getUserPhone() async {
    return readStringValue<String?>(USER_PHONE);
  }

  setUserLastAttemptTime(int lastAttemptTime) {
    setValue(USER_LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME, lastAttemptTime);
  }

  Future<int> getUserLastAttemptTime() async {
    var value = await readIntValue<int>(USER_LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME);
    if (value == null) {
      return Future.value(1);
    } else {
      return Future.value(value);
    }
  }

  setUserToken(String userToken) {
    setValue(USER_TOKEN, userToken);
  }

  Future<String?> getUserToken() async {
    return readStringValue<String?>(USER_TOKEN);
  }

  _setDeviceUniqueID(String deviceID) {
    setValue(UNIQUE_ID, deviceID);
  }

  Future<String?> getDeviceUniqueID() async {
    var uID = await readStringValue<String?>(UNIQUE_ID);
    if (uID == null) {
      uID = await findDeviceUniqueID(deviceInfo);
      _setDeviceUniqueID(uID!);
    }
    return uID;
  }

  Future<bool> getWatchedIntroHome() async {
    var watchedIntroHome = await storage.read(key: WATCHED_INTRO_HOME);
    if (watchedIntroHome == null) {
      setWatchedIntroHome(true);
      return true;
    }
    return watchedIntroHome == "true";
  }

  Future<void> setWatchedIntroHome(bool watched) async {
    await storage.write(key: WATCHED_INTRO_HOME, value: watched.toString());
  }

  Future<bool> getWatchedIntroOrder() async {
    var watchedIntroOrder = await storage.read(key: WATCHED_INTRO_ORDER);
    if (watchedIntroOrder == null) {
      setWatchedIntroOrder(true);
      return true;
    }
    return watchedIntroOrder == "true";
  }

  Future<void> setWatchedIntroOrder(bool watched) async {
    await storage.write(key: WATCHED_INTRO_ORDER, value: watched.toString());
  }
}

 ***
````

for iOS and Android. Now that flutter enable web-support, I would like to achieve the same
thing. The problem is that the plugin flutter_local_storage_web

for web i use this link :https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/blob/develop/flutter_secure_storage_web/lib/flutter_secure_storage_web.dart
but when use for web error ,this code for web :

````
***
```class UserStoredData extends FlutterSecureStoragePlatform {
  static const _publicKey = 'publicKey';


  late DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo; // = DeviceInfoPlugin();

  static const PREFERENCE_NAME = "userPreferences";

  static const REGISTER_STATE = "registerState";

  // static const USER_NAME = "userName";
  static const DEVICE_ID = "deviceId";
  static const UNIQUE_ID = "uniqueId";
  static const USER_TOKEN = "userToken";
  static const USER_PHONE = "userPhone";
  static const USER_LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME = "userLastAttemptTime";
  static const WATCHED_INTRO_HOME = "watchedIntroHome";
  static const WATCHED_INTRO_ORDER = "watchedIntroOrder";
  static const ACTIVE_USER = "activeUser";

  UserStoredData({required this.deviceInfo});
  // /// Registrar for FlutterSecureStorageWeb
  // static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
  //  FlutterSecureStoragePlatform.instance = UserStoredData( deviceInfo: DeviceInfoPlugin());
  // }

  /// Returns true if the storage contains the given [key].
  @override
  Future<bool> containsKey({
    required String key,
    required Map<String, String> options,
  }) =>
      Future.value(
        html.window.localStorage.containsKey("${options[_publicKey]!}.$key"),
      );



  /// Encrypts and saves the [key] with the given [value].
  ///
  /// If the key was already in the storage, its associated value is changed.
  /// If the value is null, deletes associated value for the given [key].
  // Future<int?>  readIntValue<T>({
  //   String? key,
  //   Map<String, String>? options,
  // }) async {
  //   final value = html.window.localStorage["${options?[_publicKey]!}.$key"];
  //   if (value != null && int.tryParse(value) != null) {
  //     var parsedValue = int.parse(value);
  //     //  return _decryptValue(value, options);
  //     return parsedValue;
  //   } else {
  //     return null; // or provide a default value, depending on your use case
  //   }
  //
  // }

  Future<int?> readIntValue({
    String? key,
    Map<String, String>? options,
  }) async {
    final value = html.window.localStorage["${options?[_publicKey]!}.$key"];
    if (value != null && int.tryParse(value) != null) {
      return int.parse(value);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  // Future<String?> readStringValue<T>({
  //   String? key,
  //   Map<String, String>? options,
  // }) async {
  //   final value = html.window.localStorage["${options?[_publicKey]!}.$key"];
  //
  //   return _decryptValue(value, options!);
  // }


  Future<String?> readStringValue({
    String? key,
    Map<String, String>? options,
  }) async {
    final value = html.window.localStorage["${options?[_publicKey]!}.$key"];
    return value;
  }

  Future<void> write({
    String? key,
    dynamic value,
    Map<String, String>? options,
  }) async {
    final iv =
    html.window.crypto!.getRandomValues(Uint8List(12)).buffer.asUint8List();

    final algorithm = _getAlgorithm(iv);

    final encryptionKey = await _getEncryptionKey(algorithm, options!);

    final encryptedContent = await js_util.promiseToFuture<ByteBuffer>(
      crypto.encrypt(
        algorithm,
        encryptionKey,
        Uint8List.fromList(
          utf8.encode(value),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final encoded =
        "${base64Encode(iv)}.${base64Encode(encryptedContent.asUint8List())}";

    html.window.localStorage["${options[_publicKey]!}.$key"] = encoded;
  }


  crypto.Algorithm _getAlgorithm(Uint8List iv) =>
      crypto.Algorithm(name: 'AES-GCM', length: 256, iv: iv);

  Future<html.CryptoKey> _getEncryptionKey(
      crypto.Algorithm algorithm,
      Map<String, String> options,
      ) async {
    late html.CryptoKey encryptionKey;
    final key = options[_publicKey]!;

    if (html.window.localStorage.containsKey(key)) {
      final jwk = base64Decode(html.window.localStorage[key]!);

      encryptionKey = await js_util.promiseToFuture<html.CryptoKey>(
        crypto.importKey("raw", jwk, algorithm, false, ["encrypt", "decrypt"]),
      );
    } else {
      //final crypto.getRandomValues(Uint8List(256));

      encryptionKey = await js_util.promiseToFuture<html.CryptoKey>(
        crypto.generateKey(algorithm, true, ["encrypt", "decrypt"]),
      );

      final jsonWebKey = await js_util
          .promiseToFuture<ByteBuffer>(crypto.exportKey("raw", encryptionKey));
      html.window.localStorage[key] = base64Encode(jsonWebKey.asUint8List());
    }

    return encryptionKey;
  }

  /// Encrypts and saves the [key] with the given [value].
  ///
  /// If the key was already in the storage, its associated value is changed.
  /// If the value is null, deletes associated value for the given [key].


  Future<String?> _decryptValue(
      String? cypherText,
      Map<String, String> options,
      ) async {
    if (cypherText == null) {
      return null;
    }

    final parts = cypherText.split(".");

    final iv = base64Decode(parts[0]);
    final algorithm = _getAlgorithm(iv);

    final decryptionKey = await _getEncryptionKey(algorithm, options);

    final value = base64Decode(parts[1]);

    final decryptedContent = await js_util.promiseToFuture<ByteBuffer>(
      crypto.decrypt(
        _getAlgorithm(iv),
        decryptionKey,
        Uint8List.fromList(value),
      ),
    );

    final plainText = utf8.decode(decryptedContent.asUint8List());

    return plainText;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> delete({required String key, required Map<String, String> options}) {
    // TODO: implement delete
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> deleteAll({required Map<String, String> options}) {
    // TODO: implement deleteAll
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future<Map<String, String>> readAll({required Map<String, String> options}) {
    // TODO: implement readAll
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }



  setRegisterState(RegisterState registerState) {
    write(key:REGISTER_STATE ,value:registerState.index ,

    );
  }

  Future<RegisterState> getRegisterState() async {
    var state = await readIntValue(key: REGISTER_STATE);
    return RegisterState.values[state ?? 0];
  }

  setActiveUser(int userID) {
    write(key:ACTIVE_USER,value: userID);
  }

  Future<int?> getActiveUser() async {
    return readIntValue(key: ACTIVE_USER);
  }



  setDeviceID(String deviceID) {
    write(key:DEVICE_ID, value: deviceID);
  }

  Future<String?> getDeviceID() async {
    return readStringValue(key: DEVICE_ID);
  }

  setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
    write(key:USER_PHONE, value: userPhone);
  }

  Future<String?> getUserPhone() async {
    return readStringValue(key: USER_PHONE);
  }

  setUserLastAttemptTime(int lastAttemptTime) {
    write(key:USER_LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME, value: lastAttemptTime);
  }

  Future<int> getUserLastAttemptTime() async {
    var value = await readIntValue(key: USER_LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME);
    if (value == null) {
      return Future.value(1);
    } else {
      return Future.value(value);
    }
  }

  setUserToken(String userToken) {
    write(key:USER_TOKEN, value: userToken);
  }

  Future<String?> getUserToken() async {
    return readStringValue(key: USER_TOKEN);
  }

  _setDeviceUniqueID(String deviceID) {
    write(key:UNIQUE_ID, value: deviceID);
  }

  Future<String?> getDeviceUniqueID() async {
    var uID = await readStringValue(key: UNIQUE_ID);
    if (uID == null) {
      uID = await findDeviceUniqueID(deviceInfo);
      _setDeviceUniqueID(uID!);
    }
    return uID;
  }

  Future<bool> getWatchedIntroHome() async {
    var watchedIntroHome = await readStringValue(key: WATCHED_INTRO_HOME);
    if (watchedIntroHome == null) {
      setWatchedIntroHome(true);
      return true;
    }
    return watchedIntroHome == "true";
  }

  Future<void> setWatchedIntroHome(bool watched) async {
    await write(key: WATCHED_INTRO_HOME, value: watched.toString());
  }

  Future<bool> getWatchedIntroOrder() async {
    var watchedIntroOrder = await readStringValue(key: WATCHED_INTRO_ORDER);
    if (watchedIntroOrder == null) {
      setWatchedIntroOrder(true);
      return true;
    }
    return watchedIntroOrder == "true";
  }

  Future<void> setWatchedIntroOrder(bool watched) async {
    await write(key: WATCHED_INTRO_ORDER, value: watched.toString());
  }

  @override
  Future<String?> read({required String key, required Map<String, String> options}) {
    // TODO: implement read
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

}
````